# Javascript UTF-8 illegal characters when minifying

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I am trying my hand at Javascript minification using a self extracting compression based on LZW compression. In order for it to work the minified Javascript is stored in a string using the new ES6 template string delimiters.

Part of the compression involves creating a dictionary, each item in the dictionary is represent by a single UTF-8 character in the code string. This gives me around 128 dictionary entries but means that the code string will contain each character from 128-255 UTF-8.

It works well on every browser I have tried, and being the only ones I am interested in supporting. I have zero interest in supporting legacy browsers.

To see how my code fairs with existing minifiers I do a comparison, and I am more than happy with the results.

Then I thought, let's see what the various javascript minifiers will do to the my minified code. This is where I struck problems as at least half the minifiers fail and report Illegal characters. Upon examination I find that it is characters in the range 128-255 UTF-8 that are marked as illegal.

Being under the impression that javascript is compliant with ASCII, UTF-8, and UTF-16 I then try to find out why the UTF-8 string is causing these minifiers to fail. I have searched to find a list of illegal UTF-8 Javascript characters and can't find any.

Could someone please shed some light on why using UTF-8 characters inside javascript strings is causing these minifiers to fail (not one YUI minifier works), and which if any UTF-8 characters need special treatment within a Javascript template string. Note I am only interested in characters codes 128-255 as I have correctly encoded all characters below theses.

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding already and it does not represent any valid 1-byte characters with the most significant byte equal to 1. It would be more helpful if you explained how you get those illegal characters there in the very first place.

Comment: @zerkms add them to the string with `code = code.replace( /dictionaryEntry/g , String.fromCharCode(dicIndex));`  I don`t know what you mean by **does not represent any valid 1-byte characters** does that mean they should not be used in a string??? that seems wrong to me.

Comment: So you deliberately assemble a wrong string then ask why it's wrong? "that seems wrong to me" --- you may check UTF-8 standard then first to deal with facts not feelings. The code you provided is not enough to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean, wrong??? Are characters 128-256 not allowed in a string? And why are they not. I thought Javascript could use UTF-8 and UTF-16 why are these characters illegal and please provide a reference

Comment: Okay, let's start from the other side: why do you think they are valid? Have you checked UTF-8 standard?

Comment: Because Chrome, FF, Edge all run the minified code without jumping into Quirks mode, both as in line and as files.

Comment: Okay, it's good then. Does your problem still exist?

Comment: Yes it is why do the Minifiers report illegal characters? What characters are illegal and why (the why with a reference) I am not happy with "they just are." i want to know why a UTF-8 file can not use half the characters.

Comment: Because of the standard defines those as illegal. Please provide the exact bytes for the string that you have and explain in details how you get them. "i want to know why a UTF-8 file can not use" --- check the standard. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629